# Error on build in Heroku -pre-received hook declined but why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, web-deployment

I'm a newbie to deployment and having lots of issues and could really use some guidance! I have an app with the folder structure shown below. [image]

When I started the deployment, I got the backend part to deploy. Screenshot attached[image]

I did a npm build in my client folder and have the following added to the script in my backend package.json [image]
However, when I try to then deal with including the client side, I have a problem and am getting this error. [image]

I was following a tutorial that had a similar folder structure and deployed via

```js
git subtree push --prefix backend heroku master
```

I also tried 'main' based on answers on stack overflow but it didn't change the error. I am the only one doing anything with this repository (and it's currently private), have no other branches, and I have nothing that hasn't been pushed to my repository in Github (no changes made recently) so I'm not sure what this is about. Any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

I think your folder structure could be the error.
Try something like that:

```
projectName:
  -client
  -package.json
  -.env
  -index.js
```

with your project structure, Heroku can't read the index.js and the package.json. Because it is nested in your backend folder.
I think this is why you are getting this error:

> Error: Cannot find module '/app/backend/server.js'